# How can I improve the creation time of a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having a dictionary of pandas `Series`, each with their own index and all containing float numbers.

I need to create a pandas `DataFrame` with all these series, which works fine by just doing:

```
result = pd.DataFrame( dict_of_series  )
```

Now, I actually have to do this a large amount of time, along with some heavy calculation (we're in a Monte-Carlo engine).

I noticed that the part where my code was spending the most time was over this line. Obviously, this is if I sum up all the times it's been called.

I thought about caching the result but unfortunately the `dict_of_series` is almost all the time different.

I guess that what takes time is obviously the constructor has to build the global index and fill the holes and maybe there is simply no way around it, but I'm wondering if I'm not missing something obvious which slows down the process, or if there is something smarter I could do to speed it up.

Has anybody had the same experience?

Comment: are the series aligned (i.e. do they all have the same index?)

Comment: no they're not, and I assume this why it takes some time. But that's just "the way it is" like I can't really change this. I might come up with a superset of the index though, but not sure it that would help...

Comment: @nick Adding tags to 3.5 year old question is not a good idea - the addition of that tag does not lead to more results - but it bumps the question into view again - I just reviewed 2 old questions where you added the dataframe tag - both _old_. I am not sure why you did so - I hope not for the rep from editing ... bumping old stuff is not nice. The poster of this question was last seen on Jan 2015  - this is not helping anyone. If you have an answer or can seriously improve a question with chances to be answered - go ahead. But adding "datframe" to "python + pandas" does _nothing_.

Comment: @nick further to Patrick's comment above, you may want to weigh in at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379244/1709587.